# Laravel Dompdf- Change photography size

Tags: image, laravel-5, dompdf

I have a serie of photos taken with a mobile. I am trying to print a complete document in PDF (done by DOMPDF in Laravel), with text and a photo inserted in it. It works perfect, except for the photos, it got printed very very small.

I had same problem with background, but I designed it with the exact A4 size (in print point).

My question is how to modify the photographies in order to get them printed in the PDF at the size I want.

PHP Code:

```
$cliente = Cliente::findOrFail($id);
$view = \View::make('cpanel.pdf.curriculum', compact('cliente'))->render();
$pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadHTML($view);
return $pdf->download('cv-'.$cliente->nombre." ".$cliente->apellidos."-".Date('d-m-Y').'.pdf');
```

I tried with css rules, but DOMPDF ignores it for images

```
<img style="width: 125pt;border: 1px solid red;" src="{{URL::asset('/images/candidatos/'.$cliente->foto)}}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of asset {{URL::asset('/images/candidatos/'.$cliente->foto)}} use  relative url eg . "home/public_html/img/imagename.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

there is a semicolon after style= replace it with double quotes

Comment: Bad typing on copy/paste here. Edited.